# Side by side error running Interactive Brokers API with Matlab on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: matlab, api, windows64, interactive-brokers

Recently I have tried to connect to Interactive Brokers API using Trading Toolbox on Matlab 2015a running on Windows 7 (64 Bit) machine. TWS and IB API were installed already.

Matlab was throwing a side by side eror.

Windows Event Viewer Error Log was the following:

Activation context generation failed for "C:\TWS API\bin\ActiveX\Tws.ocx". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

First I have searched for solutions by error messages. There were several recommendations but they were not specific to Windows 64 bit and were not working in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked was described in Interactive Brokers API reference Guide [here](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api.htm) (ActiveX > Running the ActiveX API on 64-bit Windows XP Systems).

It involved installing these dependencies:

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
2. Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 Redistributable Package.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try the cross-platform IB-Matlab product, which is Java-based (not ActiveX):

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ib-matlab

IB-Matlab doesn't have such problems, it is very reliable.